# Create custom column using criteriaBuilder

Tags: sql, advanced-custom-fields

How can I create a custom column using `criteriaBuilder`?
I need create the following:

```
select "Total" as custom_column, sum (price) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution,
use criteriaBuilder.literal("Total").
At.